# Getting Cannot invoke method assetBaseUrl() on null object exception while running grails application with inline grails plugin

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-plugin, grails-3.0, grails3

I am running a grails 3 application with an inline grails plugin.
I have written this line in build.gradle.

```
compile project(':document-management-system')
```

and written these lines in setting.gradle file.

```
include 'document-management-system'
project(':document-management-system').projectDir = new File('/file/path')
```

After running grails application i got the following exception. However if i remove that build.gradle line code then it is working fine.

```
Exception: Error processing GroovyPageView: [views/login/auth.gsp:4] Error executing tag <asset:stylesheet>: Cannot invoke method assetBaseUrl() on null object] with root cause

    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method assetBaseUrl() on null object
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetMethodTagLib$_closure1.doCall(AssetMethodTagLib.groovy:26)
    at org.grails.taglib.TagOutput.captureTagOutput(TagOutput.java:64)
    at org.grails.taglib.TagLibraryMetaUtils$_registerMethodMissingForTags_closure3.doCall(TagLibraryMetaUtils.groovy:58)
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetsTagLib$_closure7.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:130)
    at org.grails.taglib.TagOutput.captureTagOutput(TagOutput.java:64)
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetsTagLib$_closure2$_closure12.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:48)
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetsTagLib$_element_closure9.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:86)
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetsTagLib.element(AssetsTagLib.groovy:85)
    at asset.pipeline.grails.AssetsTagLib$_closure2.doCall(AssetsTagLib.groovy:46)
    at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage.invokeTagLibClosure(GroovyPage.java:410)
    at org.grails.gsp.GroovyPage.invokeTag(GroovyPage.java:335)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check for correct version of assets pipeline in both the inline plugin application and Grails application

Comment: I checked it. For Application it has the version 3.2.1 and for the plugin it has the version 2.14.2. So should i change the plugin version?

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a Charm.